# Magento header childhtml dropdown

Tags: php, jquery, html, css, magento

How do I add a child html block as a pop-up when I click a link in the header? In this link, I want to make "My Account" have a drop-down similar to the hover for the heart and bag icons.

When I tried creating a new .xml file, I used:

```
<layout>
    <default>
        <reference name="head">
            <action method="addCss"><stylesheet>css/popup.css</stylesheet></action>
              <action method="addJs"><script>dojo.xd.js</script></action>
        </reference>
                 <reference name="header">
            <block type="myaccountpopup" name="myaccountpopup" template="myaccountpopup.phtml" />
        </reference
    </default>
</layout>
```

I also added `<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('myaccountpopup') ?>` after the link to no avail.

Questions are

1. How do I determine the block type?
2. What is the proper way of getting this to work?

Answer (score 0):

May be your missing proper tag for js including :

```
<action method="addJs"><script>dojo.xd.js</script></action> // <--- Here Error
```

Answer (score 0):

Default block class is `Mage_Core_Block_Template`. If any phtml file have rendering from a block class.
Example:- `<block type="page/html_topmenu" name="catalog.topnav" template="page/html/topmenu.phtml"/>`
Here `topmenu.phtml` have call class `Mage_Page_Block_HTML_Topmen`
In your code, you have not closed reference  tag.

```
<reference name="header">
    <block type="core/template" name="myaccountpopup" template="myaccountpopup.phtml" />
</reference>
```